# Move data between view controllers, and display the moved data in the web view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am showing a book page through WebView.

I created a table view controller that shows the table of contents.
I want to load the WebView when I click the Table of Contents table cell.

If the page currently being viewed is 10, and the 10 page content is shown in the web view.

When I press the table of contents (page 19) that I want to show in the table of contents view controller, the table of contents table view disappears and I want to show the contents of page 19 as a web view.

However, the controller (ReadBookVC) and the table of contents table view controller (ChapterVC) that show the book on WebView are not connected in the storyboard.

```
 func pageView(_ page: Int) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "example.com?book_no=\(Int(bookNo ?? "") ?? 0)&book_page=\(page)")!)
        // request load
        webView?.load(request)
    }
```

The pageView function serves to show the book in WebView in ReadBookVC.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        func chapterReload() -> Void {
            readBookViewController?.pageView(Int(chaptersList?.chapters[indexPath.row].chapterPage ?? "") ?? 0)

        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: chapterReload)

    }
```

I pass the page of the table of contents (`Int (chaptersList? .Chapters [indexPath.row] .chapterPage ??") ?? 0`) to the ReadBookVC's pageView function, `Int (chaptersList? .Chapters [indexPath.row] .chapterPage ??"") ?? 0` page in the webview.

But when the chapterReload function is executed

`readBookViewController? .pageView (Int (chaptersList? .chapters [indexPath.row] .chapterPage ?? ") ?? 0)`

I noticed that I did not run this code at all.

Why `readBookViewController? .PageView (Int (chaptersList? .Chapters [indexPath.row] .chapterPage ?? ") ?? 0)`

Is the code not running?

Comment: Why are you dismissing the `chapterReload` controller ? Where are you creating instance of `readBookViewController` ? How are you showing `readBookViewController `?

Comment: @SharadChauhan

readBookViewController

On top of ChapterVC

```readBookViewController: ReadBookViewController?```

I declared this

```dismiss (animated: true, completion: chapterReload)```

The reason I used it is that I did not connect ReadVC with the cell in ChapterVC, so when I pressed the cell, ChapterVC was closed and I tried to execute ```chapterReload```

Comment: no need to connect in the storyboard. you can do the navigation through storyboard ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few changes you need to do:

In `ChapterVC`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    chapterReload(pageNumber: indexPath.row)
    //dismiss(animated: true, completion: chapterReload) No need to dismiss
}

func chapterReload(pageNumber: Int) {
    let readBookViewController                = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReadBookViewController") as! ReadBookViewController //Give Storyboard ID as ReadBookViewController for ReadBookViewController in storyboard
    readBookViewController?.chapterPageNumber = pageNumber
    self.present(readBookViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then declare a variable in `ReadBookViewController`.

```
var chapterPageNumber: Int!
```

Use `chapterPageNumber` in `ReadBookViewController` to show the page. And when you are done, you should dismiss `ReadBookViewController`.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> Why readBookViewController? .PageView (Int (chaptersList? .Chapters
>   [indexPath.row] .chapterPage ?? ") ?? 0)

Because you are dismissing a controller and in completion you are calling a function of that controller only. How its gonna a call a function of a controller which has no instance (dismissed or popped) ?